# Updating file: Method 'Worksheets' of object '_workbook' failed

Tags: vba, excel

I have 3 Excel files, one is a report where all the code is, another is an .xls SAP BI import file and a status file. Both of these are saved on a network server. The import file is constant as a template, while the status file is written, sheet by sheet.

My macros get data from the report and the import file, columns mostly, put them in the status file and do some comparisons between the figures.

It works on my computer and network, but when I change to the client's network server, I receive the error.

[image: Error]

The status workbook can be created and can be opened, but if I try to access the worksheet I need updated, it crashes.

My guess is that the error comes from the client's address which contains parentheses, example:

> I:_Other_Site\CENTER_(F-SERVER)\A-CENTRAL\00902\DIGITAL\01. Working Card BT\02. Working files\

While my company's network address is more akin to

> Z:\Clients\Working Files\"usernamefolder"\

I've tried putting the file name and path in variables and even hardcoded the sheet names in VBA. Here's a code snippet:

```
Dim sPath, sFile_s, strSheetName As String
Dim wb_s As Workbook

sPath = "I:\_Other_Site\CENTER_(F-SERVER)\A-CENTRAL\00902\DIGITAL\01. Working Card BT\02. Working files\"
sFile_s = sPath & "Import Status.xlsx"

Set wb_s = Workbooks.Open(sFile_s)

wb_s.Activate
strSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name

'some code here to open the other files'

wb_s.Worksheets(strSheetName).Activate 'here it errors out
```

Comment: Could you instead of `strSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name`  do `strSheet = ActiveSheet`? You dim the strSheet as Worksheets, and then you do `strSheet.Activate`

Comment: I've tried it and I get the same error.

Comment: `sPath` and `sFile_s` are declared as `variant`, not `string`. This is an old pitfall. Add `as string, ` after every variable.

Comment: Tried changing those too, still same error unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

`strSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name` is getting the name of active worksheet in the current/development workbook (not the wb_s). Change this to `strSheetName = wb_s.ActiveSheet.Name`

Comment: `wb_s.Activate
strSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name` is formulated to do that, take the name of the newly created worksheet and store it in a variable to be used later when I will do a copy of the working status file. I've tried your change, but unfortunately I am receiving the same error.

Comment: How about `wb_s.Sheets(strSheetName).Activate`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! I've tried that too, it works on my PC, but on the customers network it doesn't. Somehow, it doesn't get the name of the sheet if there are more than one.. Maybe there's a FR specific I am missing in the server address ? Idk.. I'll try and move all the folders locally and then upload the results at the end on the server.